# Regular expression, remove the last specific character in the string with jQuery

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I want to continue one task because my head has some problem with a regular expression. How can it be done with a regular expression and jQuery?

I have this HTML:

```
<div class="test">&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;Presentation Text   </div>
```

And I want to get just this text from all this string, every time at the beginning I have

" `&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&gt;&nbsp;`" + Some text  ... these special character are not changing every time at the begin .

One way is:

```
$('.test').html($('.test').html().replace(/&[^;]+;/g, ''));
```

It works, but I realized that I have at the end some bad characters and I have to remove "`\n\n\n`" as well

My output:

```
Presentation Text\n\n\n
```

But I need the clean text without  "`\n`" or something else, just "`Presentation Text`"

What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using jQuery, you can use [`$.trim`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/) to remove white-spaces from the beginning and end of your string.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.test').html($('.test').html().replace(/&[^;]+;|\s+$/g, ''));
```

This will remove all the whitespace characters (`\n`, `\t`, space etc) from the end of the text.